# How often can I visit the USA on ESTA in one year?

Tags: usa, esta

Does anyone know how long a 'reasonable amount of time outside the U.S. in between stays' really is?

I am dating a guy who lives there, this year I have visited three times and I am hoping on a fourth visit. The visits were for 10 days in April, 10 days in June and 25 days in Aug/Sep. I am hoping to go back end of November until 8th January. I am currently studying at uni, hence all holidays and I also have employment here so enough money to cover my stays.

After reading horror stories I'm just concerned I'll get turned away. Is anyone else in transatlantic relationships that have visited the states often??

Comment: The rest of that [statement](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1072/~/about-the-electronic-system-for-travel-authorization-%28esta%29) is: "When traveling to the U.S. with the approved ESTA, you may only stay for up to 90 days at a time - and there should be a reasonable amount of time between visits **so that the CBP Officer does not think you are trying to live here**. There is no set requirement for how long you must wait between visits." (emphasis mine)

Comment: And besides, as a repeat VWP visitor you are eligible to use the new passport kiosks and will not likely be asked much of anything beyond do you have anything to declare.